# Jquery Mobile:After selected a option in select list.The page scroll to top

Tags: android, jquery, jquery-mobile, galaxy

I found this issue on Samsung Galaxy SIII,but it's work well in iOS device.

Thank.

Comment: What's your question? what is the issue here is hard to get.

Comment: show some code/examples

Comment: thanks,The issue have been resolved.

Comment: @FreshManJ2ee i have exactly same problem. and the page is here: http://www.mersin-mezitli-satilik-daire.com/mersinmezitlisatilikdaire/welcome/detay how did you solve this